# How to fix can not save pptm file to ppam,

Tags: vba, powerpoint, add-in

I wrote several macros in a ppt file and save the file as pptm file,

All the macros in the pptm files work very well, no any bugs or errors during the running.

I tried to save it to a ppam file, but it always pops up

"powerpoint could not compile the visual basic for application code associtaed with this presentation"

Any method or idea could fix/solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: This information is not enough to reproduce the Problem. Can you share more about what type of codes are there ? or maybe you can try to create a blank `ppam` and add codes to it one by one, that ways you can find the code creating problems.

Comment: In your PPTM, in the VBA Editor, you have a menu Debug > Compile VBA Project that will popup the compilation errors (one at a time). Pay  attention to first enable the macros when opening the PPTM

Comment: the codes work very well in the pptm file, no any bug or errors. I tried to make these macros to be add-ins, so first I need to save the pptm file as ppam file,  the error
"powerpoint could not compile the visual basic for application code associtaed with this presentation" pops up when I save my pptm file to ppam file.

Comment: @together Have you tried Olivier's suggestion? If not, please explain why not.